Is Using Resistors in Doubly Tuned Transformer Impedance Matching Circuits for Low-Frequency High-Power Transducers Advisable Despite Power Loss?
I am designing an impedance matching circuit for a transducer with frequency-dependent reactance, adopting a doubly tuned transformer structure. I have heard that impedance matching circuits are generally designed to be lossless (reactive). However, the adopted circuit includes resistors in the Q factor equation to achieve wideband matching, allowing for a maximum power factor (nearly 1) within my desired frequency range.
While this approach can achieve a high power factor, I am concerned about the power loss caused by resistors dissipating energy. In this kind of circuit, resistors enable maximum power factor in the interested frequency range, but they also lead to power dissipation. Should resistors still be avoided in such matching circuits, or can they be used within certain limits? This design is intended for a low-frequency high-power system.
Any insights or references on incorporating resistors in this context would be greatly appreciated!

Above figure comes from the paper "Second-Order Equivalent Circuits for the Design of Doubly-Tuned Transformer Matching Networks" by [Andrea Mazzanti], [2018]. The original document can be accessed here, though access permissions might be required.

R1 and R2 might be regarded as the internal (and unavoidable) resistances of the windings of the transformer. You should link the document that the image came from (not only for uncovering what those resistors actually represent but also to follow site rules on citations for borrowed images).

I have added the link to the original document, though it seems that access permissions are required to view it. Apologies for any inconvenience. From my reading, it does seem that R1 and R2 are indeed internal resistances, as you pointed out.

I don't think you should adopt or favour any scheme without getting into the values of input impedance, output impedance, centre-frequency and bandwidth. I don't think the IEEE document is going to help you solve that because it's intended (or so it seems) for millimetre wavelengths. I quote this from the accessible part of the document: -
The doubly-tuned magnetic transformer, comprising coupled inductors shunted by capacitors, 
is today widely in use as interstage network and for impedance matching in silicon 
millimeter waves amplifiers

I suspect that your application might be more in the high kHz or low/medium MHz range thus totally ruling out the IEEE technique but, favours good old fashioned standard methods of impedance matching such as using transformers and LC networks. Of course, without numbers, I cannot advise what specific circuit you should use.
I can help you with this but, no numbers means very little help.
